# Single time user authentication in Android app

Tags: android, authentication, mobile

I am rebuilding an Android app and want to authenticate users only once (the very first time they use the app). From that point on, I would like for users to be saved to the db so they can have quicker access to their account without having to sign in every single time they use it.

Thank you!